# No timestamp when transfering AWS WAF logs from S3 to ES

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-waf

1.Hi guys I am trying to transfer the AWS WAF logs From S3 to Elastic Search
while creating index i give the index prefix and then while choosing timestamp this is what i get
[refer image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNg0H.png)

2.i then referred some solutions online https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-kinesis-agent/issues/108 According to the solution in the link i added the mapping template too
this is what i added:

```
PUT /lb*/_mapping
 {

            "properties":{
                "timestamp":{
                    "type":"date",
                    "format":"dd/MMM/YYYY HH:mm:ss,SSS"
                }
            }
        }
```

3.After adding the template while choosing the timestamp the timestamp appeared as in this 
[refer image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhbeV.png)

4. Atlast after creating the index this is what i get 
   [refer image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTTFj.png)

not sure what i am missing.Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

For the timestamp mapping, it should be something like this

```
PUT  _template/awswaf-logs
    {
        "index_patterns": ["awswaf-*"],
        "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1
        },
        "mappings": {
          "waflog": {
            "properties": {
              "httpRequest": {
                "properties": {
                  "clientIp": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "ip"
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "timestamp": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "epoch_millis"
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

You may refer to https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-analyze-aws-waf-logs-using-amazon-elasticsearch-service/ for more detail